# What is the alternative for -fpermssive flag in windows (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I am using third party code(openssl) from our product code. While compiling the code, I am getting the errors which can be suppressed as warnings using -fpermissive flag in Linux (gcc/g++). In windows, I am getting the same compilation errors in visual studio (2005). Would like to know the alternative of -fpermissive flag that can be used in visual studio to suppress the errors.

I tried adding the flags such as '/fpermissive' , '/Ze' in module properties->C/C++->command Line->Additional options. But it did not resolve the problem.

Getting the errors like below.
ssl/packet_locl.h(429) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char *'Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Since it is giving error in third party code, we can not make any code changes there.

Expected results: We need to suppress this error as warning and then proceed with compilation successfully.

Comment: TL;DR: [No, you can't just disable hard errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104646/is-there-a-way-to-disable-certain-errors-under-vs2008). Are you compiling C code with a  C++ compiler? If so, the overall problem can be solved (but not by suppressing errors).

Comment: Hi Max, yes I am compiling C++ code with C code (Openssl). Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Then the solution is to wrap all the openssl stuff in a C library that you compile with a C compiler. Your C++ code then interfaces with this wrapper library (whose headers _don't_ transitively include `ssl/packet_locl.h` etc.). This has probably already been done by someone else (you're certainly not the first one(s) to use openssl with C++ code), so you should look for such a C++ binding of openssl.

Answer (score 0):

**>>I tried adding the flags such as '/fpermissive' , '/Ze' in module properties->C/C++->command Line->Additional options.**

That is define on gcc, you cannot use on VS. This is not suitable for VS.

**>>cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char 'Conversion from 'void' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast**

These are errors defined by the language. You can't ignore these errors and run the program directly. They cannot be compiled.

**>>Since it is giving error in third party code, we can not make any code changes there.**

If you strictly abide by the method to use the interfaces of these third party libraries, There will be no such errors. What your need is modifying your own code, not changing the third party library code.

Comment: It is showing the error in the header file of openssl. How can I change the code in my module, when the error is in other module.